How to visualize Android Seekbar like whatsapp voice message
I am building an android application and I have a voice chat part. I want to show the voice style and playing voice style message like WhatsApp messages/records. I tried a lot of ways but nothing work and I tried to use GitHub libraries but those did not work with me.
How can I do that in android?
And can I do that without using an external library?

whatsapp is built using react

Can I make the same thing with android ?

In jetpack compose its easy to build it then xml

I solved the issue.
I just used this GitHub library and it work with me.
I added my audio to the xml widget using setSampleFrom method to visualize the voice modulation and then I used mediaPlayer to play my voice and track there progress in the modulation waves.
